# When I start a multiplayer game in GameCenter it doesn't go to the GamePlay....Why?

Tags: ios, xcode, game-center, multiplayer

Im testing out my game that is using multiplayer real time with game center and when I press play now and it finds the match it doesnt go past Starting game. It just keeps loading and doesnt go to the gameplay. Why does this happen? Heres the code I have: BTW Im using my iPhone 5s and the simulator for iPhone 5s in xcode to test the multiplayer....is that okay?

```
    func findMatchPlease() {
    let matchRequest = GKMatchRequest()
    matchRequest.minPlayers = 2
    matchRequest.maxPlayers = 2


    let mmvc = GKMatchmakerViewController(matchRequest: matchRequest)
    mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self
    let viewController = self.scene?.view?.window?.rootViewController
    viewController?.presentViewController(mmvc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}




override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {

        var touch: UITouch = touches.first as! UITouch
        var location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        var node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

        if node.name == "find" {

            var goToMatch = GamePlay(size: self.size)
            var transitionToMatch = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(1.0)
            goToMatch.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill
            self.scene!.view?.presentScene(goToMatch, transition: transitionToMatch)


        findMatchPlease()

        }


    }


}
```

Comment: I got it to work but when I get to my gameplay its two separate games. When I move my node in my device it doesnt move on my simulator. Same thing happens with my simulator.

Comment: how did you get it to work? I am so stuck on this, Please help

Comment: @Jesster2k10 This is the ray multiplayer tutorial converted to swift. But im stuck trying to connect the devices and share the data. When I get to the gameplay the simulator and device are two seperate games.https://github.com/jasonpaulwong/SwiftGameCenter/tree/32e8beeda46edfdbc9b1d039c48640c355930c25

Comment: theres alot of errors in the code..